# How to simplify $\pi = 2 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_n \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_n}{\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)_n} \frac{1^n}{n!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, pi

I'd like to make this series self contained by not relying upon outside knowledge such as  [Pochhammer symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials)

$$\pi = 2 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_n \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_n}{\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)_n} \frac{1^n}{n!}$$

Tried something ugly like

$$2 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\frac{1}{2}(\frac{3}{2})\cdots(\frac{1}{2}+n-1))^2}{\frac{3}{2}(\frac{5}{2})\cdots(\frac{3}{2}+n-1)n!} $$

but not sure if it's an equivalent formula or could be tidied up further?

The main reason is I'd like to write a *simple* C program to calculate this $\pi$ formula based on $n$.

**Edit**

Based upon the accepted answer, the [new formula](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Sum%5B1%2F%281%2F2%20%2B%20n%29%20Factorial2%5B2%20n%20-%201%5D%2Fn%21%201%2F2%5En%2C%20%7Bn%2C%200%2C%20Infinity%7D%5D) is

$$\large \pi = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2n-1)!!}{2^n \cdot (n+\frac{1}{2}) \cdot n!}$$

or without the double factorial

$$\large \pi = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n} (n!)^2} \cdot \frac{2}{2n+1}$$

Comment: Well, you could replace $1^n$ with $1.$

Comment: $$(\frac32)_n=\frac32\cdot (\frac12)_{n-1}$$ and $$(\frac12)_n=(\frac32-n)\cdot (\frac12)_{n-1}$$

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Arcsine_Function_in_terms_of_Gaussian_Hypergeometric_Function

Comment: This series converges very slowly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you're looking for is a simplification you can use the definition $(a)_n=\Gamma(a+n)/\Gamma(a)$ and the property $\Gamma(z+1)=z\Gamma(z)$ to write
$$
\begin{aligned}
\pi
&=2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(1/2)_n (1/2)_n}{(3/2)_n} \frac{1^n}{n!}\\
&=2\frac{\Gamma(3/2)}{\Gamma(1/2)}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\Gamma(1/2+n) }{\Gamma(3/2+n)} \frac{(1/2)_n}{n!}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{1/2+n}\frac{(1/2)_n}{n!}.
\end{aligned}
$$

If you cannot use the Pochhammer symbol but double factorials are fine note that
$$
(1/2)_n=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{3}{2}\cdot\frac{5}{n}\cdots\frac{2n-1}{2}=\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdots(2n-1)}{2^n}=\frac{(2n-1)!!}{2^n}
$$
So that we have the equivalent form
$$
\begin{aligned}
\pi
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(2n-1)!!}{1/2+n}\frac{2^{-n}}{n!}.
\end{aligned}
$$

Typing

```
Sum[1/(1/2 + n) Factorial2[2 n - 1]/n! 1/2^n, {n, 0, Infinity}]
```

into Mathematica does in fact return the value $\pi$.

---

**Edit:**

I do not write in C but chat GPT does.  Here is C code to sum up the first eleven terms

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double factorial2(int n) {
    double res = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        res *= (2 * i - 1);
    }
    return res;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    double sum = 0;
    for (n = 0; n <= 10; n++) {
        double term = 1 / ((1.0 / 2) + n) * factorial2(2 * n - 1) / tgamma(n + 1) * pow(0.5, n);
        sum += term;
    }
    printf("%.15f\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This symbol is the falling factorial on the Wikipedia page lined to above.

Comment: The double factorial can be replaced since $(2n-1)!!=\frac{(2n)!}{2^n \cdot n!}$, then $$\pi =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n-1} \cdot (2n+1) \cdot (n!)^2}$$

Comment: @vengy That is certainly another option. There are many different ways we could represent this series.

Answer (score 2):

You could continue simplifying since
$$(2n-1)!!=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi }}2^n \Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)$$
$$\pi=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(2n-1)!!}{n+\frac 12}\,\frac{2^{-n}}{n!}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi }}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{2 n+1}{2} \right)}{(2 n+1)\, \Gamma (n+1)}$$ which gives
$$\frac{\pi ^{3/2}}{2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{2 n+1}{2} \right)}{(2 n+1)\, \Gamma (n+1)}$$ which shows how slow would be the convergence.

Suppose that we want to stop summing when
$$\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{2 n+1}{2} \right)}{(2 n+1)\, \Gamma (n+1)} \leq \epsilon$$ This gives
$$n \geq -\frac{5}{12\,\, W\left(-\frac{5}{6}\sqrt[3]{\frac{\epsilon ^2}{2}}\right)}$$ For $\epsilon=10^{-16}$, this would give $n>2.92402\times 10^{10}$.